# Index Match to List All Types of Program Managers Per Team

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of employee data and I want to extract anyone who is any type of "Program Manager". For example, there's "Senior Program Manager", "Technical Program Manager", "UX Program Manager", and I want to get their username.

In this [Employee Data table](https://i.imgur.com/MJYvxDV.png), I am trying to figure how to extract all types of Program Manager per team so my dynamic spreadsheet would look like this:

| Team | Program Manager |
| --- | --- |
| A-team | kevinchen (Sr. Technical Program Manager) |
| B-team | lisalu (Program Manager), jengomez (Technical Program Manager) |
| C-team | joannwynn (Senior Program Manager), jackiechan (UX Program Manager), kenle (Senior Program Manager) |

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G3PvU_7S0LrJmKfFk76qzMbeLcv4cXri0fzWRMDddzI/edit#gid=0)

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using index match and regular expression but I'm getting "#Error!" message.
`=IF(ISBLANK(C2),"",index(employee_data!B:B,match(1,(employee_data!A:A="A-team")*('list of ppl'!J:J="*Product Manager"),0)))"))))"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,filter({A:A,B:B&" ("&C:C&")"},regexmatch(C:C,"Program Manager")),
     byrow(unique(index(Σ,,1)),lambda(Λ,{Λ,join(", ",filter(index(Σ,,2),index(Σ,,1)=Λ))})))
```

[image]